# Error in getMetricsFromLatex when using \includegraphics before \begin{document}

Tags: r, latex, knitr, tikz, tikzdevice

Following Code compiles successfully, but the plot doesn't work (Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics, verbose =verbose): TeX was unable to calculate metrics ...)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usefoottemplate{{\includegraphics[scale=0.045]{Rlogo.png}}}%

\begin{document}
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(tikzDevice)
options(tikzDefaultEngine='xetex')
opts_chunk$set(dev="tikz")
@

\begin{frame}[fragile]
<<fig.width=2, fig.height=2>>=
data <- c(1, 2, 3)
barplot(table(data))
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I delete `\includegraphics...` in the Code above everything works fine.

Comment: Your example works fine for me (although I would rather use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{...}` to format the footline). `\usefoottemplate` is obsolete and only still around for compatibility reasons. Can you add which version of packages, r etc. you use?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I corrected `\usefoottemplate` to `\setbeamertemplate{footline}` (although this does not affect the error message).

Just yesterday I deleted and reinstalled everything. So all packages etc. should be up to date:
R-4.1.3; 
RStudio 2022.02.1;

knitr 1.38;
tinytex 0.38;
tikzDevice 0.12.3.1